# How to translate month name in French and other language

Tags: shopify, liquid, translate

I tried to translate month name in French language but I don't get any solution any anybody else have solution please let us know.

This is my liquid code i want from and to variable value in French language for month name.

```
{%- liquid
            assign range = 2 | times: 24 | times: 60 | times: 60
            assign deliver_in =  block.settings.deliver_days | times: 24 | times: 60 | times: 60
            assign now = 'now' | date: "%s"
            assign from = now | plus: deliver_in | minus: range | date: "%b %d"
            assign to = now | plus: deliver_in | plus: range | date: "%b %d"
          -%}
          <div class="deliver-text">
            <p><strong>{{ block.settings.deliver_text | strip_html }}</strong><span> {{ from }} - {{ to }}</span></p>
          </div>
```

**Thank you in advance**